# Как посчитать количество вариантов PYTHON

Tags: python

```
from itertools import permutations
for item in permutations('АБС', 2):
        print(''.join(item))
```

Вывод программы:

АБ
АС
БА
БС
СА
СБ

Нужно посчитать количество вариантов, которая выдаёт программа.

Comment: len(permutations('АБС', 2))

Comment: @Jack_oS `permutations` возвращает итератор, длину которого нельзя узнать с помощью len

Comment: @Danis ```permutations``` возвращает объект типа ```itertools.permutations```, но у него, все равно, нет ```len()```.... тогда:  ```len([i for i in permutations('АБС', 2)])```

Comment: [Чтобы поблагодарить автора ответа, проголосуйте за ответ или отметьте его как решение.](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 2):

То, что Вы хотите сделать, в математике называется размещением. Вам надо узнать количество размещений `k` элементов из `n`-элементного множества.   Идём на [википедию](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A0%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%89%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5) и видим формулу:

> A<sup>k</sup><sub>n</sub> = n! / (n-k)!

Можно получить количество размещений самому по этой формуле. Либо использовать уже готовую имплементацию из встроенной библиотеки [`math`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/math.html): [`math.perm`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/math.html#math.perm).

Данным способом считать в разы быстрее, чем счёт перебором (сложность **O(1)** против **O(n)**).

Answer (score 1):

используйте `math.perm`

```
import math

a = "АБС" 
b = 2
print(math.perm(len(a), b))
```

Comment: **math.perm** - new in version **3.9**